# Problem trying to get database information (mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in Discord.js and I need the database to retrieve and also rewrite information about the job of a particular person
**For example:**
User 1 wants to work as a farmer so user 1 will type `.job farmer` and his information will be stored or rewritten.

I'm using mysql2

This is the code I used for the table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id CHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
    money INT,
    stable TINYINT,
    job VARCHAR(15),
    banned INT
);
```

This is the code I'm using for the job command(The comments in capital letters  highlight where I might be having problems but I don't know how to fix them).

```
const db = require('../db.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'job',
    description: 'selecione um trabalho para trabalhar',
    group: 'economia',
    aliases: ['trabalho','jobs','trabalhos'],

    async execute(message, args){
        const user_id = message.author.id;
        const [rows] = await db.query(`SELECT job FROM users WHERE id = ${user_id}`);

        var jobs = ['pintor','fazendeiro','pedreiro'];
        

        // create row
        if (rows[0] == undefined){
            db.query(`INSERT INTO users (ID, MONEY, STABLE, BANNED) VALUES (${user_id}, 0, 10, 0)`);
            
            if (!args[0]){
                message.reply(`Profissões disponíveis: ${jobs}. \n Para selecionar uma apenas passe o argumento depois de "job" no comando`);
            }

        } 
        
        if (args.length == 1){ // check for args 
            if(jobs.includes(args[0])){
                await db.query(`UPDATE users SET job = '${args[0]}' WHERE id = ${user_id}`); //HERE IT WON'T UPDATE THE JOB
                return message.reply(`agora você é um ${args}`);
            }
            else{
                message.reply('não existe essa profissão... Profissões disponíveis: carpinteiro, pintor.');
            }
        }
       
            
        
        
        // user has a job
        if (rows[0] !== null) {
            message.reply(`você é um ${rows[0]}. \n Profissões disponíveis: pintor, carpinteiro.`);
        } //PROBLEM HERE WHERE IT SHOWS '[object Object]' INSTEAD OF THE ACTUAL JOB 
        // doesn't have a job
        else {
            message.reply(`profissões disponíveis: ${jobs}. \n Para selecionar uma apenas passe o argumento depois de "job" no comando`);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a seriously old version of MySQL.  Are you sure?  :)  `SELECT VERSION();` to verify.

Comment: the version is 8.0.26

Comment: okay so I fixed the major problem which was the updating of the table, now I just need to fix the part where it shows [object Object] 
the table wasn't updating because I didn't include the '' on the values to be inserted into the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem which was the updating of the table, the table wasn't updating because I didn't include the ' ' on the values to be inserted into the row.

I have fixed it already
where it said:

```
const [rows] //rest of code
```

I changed to:

```
const [rows,fields]//rest of code
```

I got this problem because I thought I didn't need 'fields' in there as my editing program was telling me that 'fields' was defined but never used so I thought, weellll I'll just delete this then... (turns out it was a dumb idea and I had totally forgotten about this)